# How to invert selected tab colors in tmux?

Tags: colors, console, tmux, archlinux

Recently I moved to Tmux instead of windows managers (Without X). 
Yet I use a Python package called Pywal for my color themes.

What I want is to bring focus to the selected tab on the status bar by swapping its background and foreground color, `fg <-> bg`.

Are there some ways to invert a tab color.

```
fg = bg
bg = fg
```

Or a way to extract the colors used by pywal and using them in `tmux.comf`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the colors of the current tab like this:

```
setw -g window-status-current-fg 7
setw -g window-status-current-bg 0
```

The numbers refer to the colors from your colorscheme.

**EDIT**: You can also invert the colors for the current tab:

```
setw -g window-status-current-style reverse
```